# Handle default exception in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

How do I implement default behavior for an Exception? `begin rescue else` doesn't work(which I think should).

And, isn't `else` meaningless in the scenario? Any code that has to run when no exception is raised does run between the `begin-rescue` block.

By the way I have the following workaround, but I'm not satisfied with it.

```
class MyException < Exception
end

class YourException < Exception
end

begin
  raise MyException if 2 > 50
  raise YourException if 1 < 90
rescue Exception => e
  case e.message
  when /MyException/
    puts "MyException Caught"
  else
    puts "Default Exception Caught"
  end
end
```

Comment: Should have done the following: rescue MyException and then rescue Exception (Don't know why I didn't do that before. :( )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you *really* shouldn't subclass [`Exception`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Exception.html). It is the superclass of **all** Ruby exceptions, including [`NoMemoryError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NoMemoryError.html), [`SyntaxError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/SyntaxError.html), [`Interrupt`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Interrupt.html), [`SystemExit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/SystemExit.html); all of which you don't normally need to rescue from. Doing so, whether accidentally or on purpose, is discouraged since it can prevent a program from exiting properly, even if it was interrupted by the user. It can also hide or produce some quite obscure bugs.

What you want to subclass is [`StandardError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/StandardError.html), which is the superclass of most Ruby errors we see in day-to-day programming. This class is also the one which will be `rescue`d should you not specify one:

```
begin
  object.do_something!
rescue => error    # will rescue StandardError and all subclasses
  $stderr.puts error.message
end
```

I believe this is the "default behavior" you are looking for. You can handle a specific error, then all other errors in general:

```
class CustomApplicationError < StandardError
end

begin
  object.do_something!
rescue CustomApplicationError => error
  recover_from error
rescue => error
  log.error error.message
  raise
end
```

---

The `else` clause is not meaningless in error handling. It will execute the nested code if and only if no exceptions were raised, as opposed to the `ensure` clause which will execute code regardless. It allows you to handle *success* cases.

```
begin
  object.do_something!
rescue => error
  log.error error.message
else
  log.info 'Everything went smoothly'
end
```

Comment: The else clause didn't mean much to me, because I was stuck to figure how to handle default exception case. As soon as I got it, else was meaningful. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: Figured out. Your second block of code is meaningful. Not to rescue "Exception" but just use rescue for other exceptions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not understand why you are case-conditioning with the error message. Why not do it with the error itself by their class? Then, it would be like this:

```
begin
  raise MyException if 2 > 50
  raise YourException if 1 < 90
rescue Exception => e
  case e
  when MyException
    puts "MyException Caught"
  else
    puts "Default Exception Caught"
  end
end
```

Second, doing it as above is not the straightforward way. The correct way to do it is:

```
begin
  raise MyException if 2 > 50
  raise YourException if 1 < 90
rescue MyException
  puts "MyException Caught"
rescue Exception
  puts "Default Exception Caught"
end
```

If `YourException` were a subclass of `StandardError`, then it could be captured by `rescue` without specifying the exception class.

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer and I figured it out later (as mentioned in the comment). Thanks though. :)